# AS3: Game development

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, game-engine

I am looking a game framework for flex/AS3. I want to use it to create simple 2d games, such as tower defense, etc.

Maybe someone can suggest something?

Comment: Also, I am looking on fisix. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this framework.  [http://flixel.org/](http://flixel.org)

It's easy to learn but very powerfull.

Comment: Do you know where I can find examples/tutorials about it?

Comment: Flixel comes packages with 'Mode' -  which is a heavily commented game developed in Flixel. There's also a few tutorials on the official forums e.g. http://flixel.org/forums/index.php?topic=226.0

Answer (score 2):

check out the Pushbutton Engine from none other than Jeff Tunnell (Incredible Machine) and his [Push Button Labs](http://www.pushbuttonlabs.com/)  .. new company spawned from Dynamix/GarageGames .. read more [here](http://gigaom.com/2009/03/28/pushbutton-open-source-flash-game-engine/)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a game framework, AS3 alone is enough to create games. I recommend the [Shootorials over at Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/search?q=shootorial). Its a step by step tutorial for creating a sidscrolling shooter. You can find the first step [here](http://www.kongregate.com/games/Kongregate/shootorial-0) and you can (if youre curious) play the intended end result [here](http://www.kongregate.com/games/Kongregate/shoot-the-shootorial-game).

[image: Thumbnail for first tutorial]

*Thumbnail for first tutorial*

**Edit:** I assumed that Flex wasnt important. If it is, some follow the ["Shootorials with free tools"](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/11/topics/23746?page=1) forum thread, also on Kongregate. I read those myself back when I tried flash, the result was.... [meh](http://mizipzor.wordpress.com/tag/swfmill/).

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[isometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection)** engine which name is **[FFilmation](http://www.ffilmation.org/website/downloads/)**, also it has got editor to create isometric place.

[image]